# error Couldn't find executable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run this command :
rosrun chefbot_bringup send_goal 1 0 1

i have this error :
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named send_goal below /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws/src/Chefbot_ROS_pkg/chefbot/chefbot_bringup

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245179/error-couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably haven't properly compiled your workspace and thus this node is not built.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-10-16**:
thanks a lot!